# Quick Liquid and animatied mesh collider

Tags: animation

I would like to know if its possible to make liquid sim with animated mesh collision.
like while I fill water into glass, I want the glass changeing its shape.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not do this with a *Boolean* modifier... at least not the fluid simulation, for the visible part of a glass changing its shape I would use dummy objects which do not effect the simulation.

For the simulation I would use the cube which you have for the Boolean operation as another *Effector*. So instead of having the glass expanding upwards to make room for the fluid, let the cube as effector push back the fluid and slowly make room for the fluid upwards.

This way the hollow space to contain the fluid is present all the time, it is only the second effector cube holding the fluid back from rising. If you want to render an animated glass which appears, I would do this with separate objects without fluid simulation.

(By the way, in the animation below I've slightly increased the *Resolution Divisions* and the *Substeps* on the *Flow* object to make sure the fluid is not leaking somewhere, but maybe that's not necessary.)

[image: rising water]

Comment: Thank you very much.